# Turn off Dropbox notifications in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dropbox

How can I prevent Dropbox from sending desktop notifications every time I alter or add a file in one of my Dropbox folders? (The code I write is saved in Dropbox, and it's terribly annoying to have a notification pop up every time I save a file etc.)

Comment: I tried that, but it has no effect on the desktop notifications.

Comment: Bonus if this can be disabled via the command line.